# Making Tool-tip Screen-reader friendly

Tags: html, tooltip, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I've implemented a tooltip in my website. The link which opens the tooltip is simple, and has the following code:

```
<a href="#tooltip" id="tooltip" class="toolTipLink">This should open a tooltip</a>
```

On focus or on click, the tooltip shows up. Everything works perfectly, till the time the screen-reader (I'm using JAWS) is turned on. When Jaws read the link, and I press enter, it doesn't show the tooltip.

This is what I've tried:

1. I've tried adding `role=dialog` on the `div` which contains tooltip
   text.
2. I also tried adding `aria-haspopup=true` on the link.

But both approaches don't seem to work. Any suggestion on how to make it work with screenreaders?

Comment: Do you have a URL? The code you provide is insufficient to test, let alone review.

Comment: The application is in development. Can't share the URL. BTW, can you give me some hint on where I should look for solution, is it the JS tooltip library issue, or HTML accessibility tag issue. Because right now, I'm clueless :)

Comment: Could you share the tooltip library? I've had bad experiences with tooltip plugins and screenreaders in the past. A custom solution might be best.

Comment: @Skerrvy Corporate policies...can't share the code online...anyway thanks for pointing out that the problem could be with JS library (its a custom built library). I'll start debugging that.

Comment: @anwartheravian maybe check if you are trying to use the enter key inside of an area where JAWS already defines an action for the enter key (eg, to enter forms mode). http://doccenter.freedomscientific.com/doccenter/archives/training/jawskeystrokes.htm

Comment: @Skerrvy yes, the link is within a form element. And just to check our assumption, I moved the link outside form element. Still same result. (Tooltp opening on enter without JAWS, when JAWS turned on, it doesn't open up)